# non secure items on secure page

Tags: ssl, https, mixed-content

I have an e-commerce site with an SSL installed. I have made sure all links are https:// to avoid getting the browser error saying there are non secure items on the page. 
However, I have a news and press feed in my footer which links to another websites which is not secure and do not have https:// available. Is there any way to fix this or are there any tricks to making this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page is loading three images from https://192.99.37.125/ which is the wrong url, as it does not match to the used certificate. That is causing the error.

Comment: Good call! I didnt know about regular links. Thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Links to HTTP URLs should not cause browser errors about non-secure items on a page. Check your browser console (F12) to see what specific items are triggering the non-secure warnings.

Comment: Well they are. Viewing the source, the only http:// link are the ones I am talking about. see screenshot: https://www.evernote.com/l/ALGaSl7OBzNNcZic64xKAGY02nhxy0_a-D4